# Processing two tasks exactly at the same time as parallel in Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I want to call 8 methods in a method.

2 methods inside of these 8 methods is one hole task, and the remaining 6 methods is another hole task.

I want to process these 2 tasks exactly at the same time as parallel.

As I know I can do it with threads. But to be honest either I couldn't see an example which is similar to my goal, or I couldn't understand the example if I've seen.

Could you briefly show me an example in order me to finish my goal?

Thanks,

Comment: Not really, because the way you presented this is too abstract to be able to give you any concrete help. You need to be a lot more specific. My advice would be, instead of looking for an ready-made example on the Internet, learn in depth about [concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), there are whole books about this subject, start from doing small exercises, and then when you have a real understanding, you'll surely be able to tackle your actual task.

Comment: Check out [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) and [arriveAndAwaitAdvance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html#arriveAndAwaitAdvance%28%29)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somethings like this maybe:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        pool.execute(() -> {
            method1();
            method2();
        });

        pool.execute(() -> {
            method3();
            /* ... */
            method8();
        });

        pool.shutdown();

        if (!pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            System.err.println("Pool did not terminate.");
    }
}
```

Comment: As per java doc: execute--> executes the given command at some time in the future. This does not always ensure that both tasks will be executed at exactly same time.

Comment: @AmitParashar: I don't think that is what yusuf meant. You can never ensure that the two tasks start exactly at the same time (for example, Sasha's code does not ensure that). If there are some kind of data dependencies between the tasks additional synchronization is needed, but then we need additional information about the problem as other commenters have already said.

Comment: Agreed about Yusuf's requirement. However, I would love an approach where one could delegate the task (independent and mutually exclusive) to two different cores. Probably, this way execution at "exactly same time" (close to the smallest unit) as computed by OS" could be achieved.

Comment: That would require some kind of non-standard OS (or at least a modified standard OS) where you would have total control over the scheduler (or at least special support for this), I think. What would you gain from such a feature?

Comment: @cic : I do not intend to downvote your response. My thought is, that one can achieve the accuracy provided by multi processor systems, if  it would be possible to implement such a feature. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in many ways, for example by using shared [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

```
public static class Task implements Runnable {

    Semaphore s;
    String name;

    public Task(Semaphore s, String name) {
        this.s = s;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + " waiting");
        try {
            s.acquire();         // wait for permit
            System.out.println(name + " continuing");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted while waiting");
        }
    }
}
```

In main code, use shared `Semaphore` to synchronize:

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
new Thread(new Task(s, "Task A")).start();
new Thread(new Task(s, "Task B")).start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
s.release(2);                  // release 2 permits to allow both threads continue
```

Output:

```
Task A waiting
Task B waiting
Task A continuing              // after 1 second
Task B continuing
```

Comment: Sasha, so where will I call my different methods in different two tasks?

Comment: @yusuf oh, I looked at another answer and I suppose I misunderstood your question. sorry

Comment: @yusuf I thought you need first to call 2 methods in each thread, then synchronize continuing at some point.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean @Sasha? :)