# Call java method2 inside another java method1 and dont wait for method2 response and continue executing

Tags: java

in the below example i dont want to wait for method 2 response. 
just call that method and continue the method1 next line code;

thank you

enter code here

```
public int Method1()
{      //code here
      //call method2
      method2(id);
       //next line codes
}
public void method2(int id)
{
//this method takes 5 second to execute;`
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Processing two tasks exactly at the same time as parallel in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257369/processing-two-tasks-exactly-at-the-same-time-as-parallel-in-java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async method followed by a parallelly executed method in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217066/async-method-followed-by-a-parallelly-executed-method-in-java-8)

Comment: You can use CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> yourServiceMethod());

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution with using Thread concept and if using spring check below given link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Using Thread:

```
    public int Method1()
    {
    //code here
          //call method2
            new Thread(new Runnable() {  //here create new Thread and start
                  public void run() { 

                     method2(id); 
                   } 
        }).start();


   //next line codes
    }


    public void method2(int id)
    {
    //this method takes 5 second to execute;
    }`
```

This is will work definitely.

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient and manual way of using threading (as you create a full new thread each time, instead of reusing them, in a thread pool), looks like 20 year old code to me. I'd suggest you to look at Javas `ExecutorService` and huge async framework, most noteable `CompleteableFuture`. There is no need to get big spring here, Java has a rich async library.